# Create QueryBuilder for find for field ManuToMany

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity Devekoper and I need find Developer whohave password and who have newreference,how I do tha I dontnow:

```
    /**
    * Developers.
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="developers")
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\DeveloperRepository")
    */
    class Developer extends CustomUser
    {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     protected $id;

         /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=80, nullable=true)
 */
protected $password;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeUserReference", inversedBy="alluser")
 */
protected $newreference;
```

and I have entity CodeUserReference in field codereference setreference for user

```
 class CodeUserReference
 {
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer", inversedBy="newreference")
 */
protected $alluser;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $codereference;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $created_at;
```

And I want find all developer who has reference of who has not reference.I try:

```
    public function getDevelopersWithRefernce()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');

    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer', 'd')

        ->addSelect('COUNT(m.id) as nMethods')
        ->join('d.newreference', 'm')
        ->groupBy('d.id')
        ->orderBy("nMethods", 'DESC')

        ->getQuery();
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

I have error SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'artel.developer_codeuserreference' doesn't exist . I need find developers who has reference or whohas not reference.Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying you that the table for CodeUserReference doesn't exist

so

```
->join(d.newreference, 'm')
```

is not going to work.

Can you please show us the header of CodeUserReference class?

Have you done the migrations to add this table to the database?

Check if this command create a file with the difference: **doctrine:migrations:diff**

```
public function getDevelopersWithRefernce()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');

    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer', 'd')
        ->leftJoin('d.newreference', 'm')
        ->where('m.codereference IS NULL')
        ->andWhere('d.password IS NULL')

        ->getQuery();
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: `/**
 * Coders 24 users
 * @ORM\Table(name="code_user_reference")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity
\CodeUserReferenceRepository")
 */
class CodeUserReference
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer", inversedBy="newreference")
     */
    protected $alluser;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $codereference;`

Comment: how to going in chat?

Comment: writing on the comments a lot. The problem is with the database, you haven't created the table, can you check that the table for CodeUserReference is created and is called code_user_reference

Comment: I have loca DataBase for test in the database have  'code_user_reference' and in this tamble have 12 row. But name in db 'code_user_reference', not artel.developer_codeuserreference.

Comment: `$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('developer');
        $queryBuilder->select(array('developer', 'u'))
            ->leftJoin('developer.newreference', 'u');
        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();`
and again - Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'artel.developer_codeuserreference' doesn't exist

Comment: I need find developer who has pasword = nulland and don't have reference:` /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeUserReference", inversedBy="alluser")
 */
protected $newreference;`

Comment: Are you still having the same problem with the database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83197/discussion-between-fernando-caraballo-and-shuba-ivan).